# Returning generic without knowing type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, types, factory

I have a situation where I have a class that accepts an instance of a certain object type in its generic type parameter. The layout is something like this:

```
public abstract BaseClass { ... }
public DiamondClass : BaseClass { ... }
public SilverClass : BaseClass { ... }

public Handler<T> where T : BaseClass { ... }
```

**I want** to be able to create a method to return an instance of `Handler<DiamondClass>` or `Handler<BaseClass>` without defining the type upon input. I've tried something along these lines:

```
public Handler<BaseClass> GetHandler(HandlerType type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case HandlerType.Diamond: return new Handler<DiamondClass>();
        case HandlerType.Silver: return new Handler<SilverClass>();
        default: throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
    }
}
```

But this won't work, because apparently `Handler<DiamondClass>` won't cast implicitly to `Handler<BaseClass>`. I can specify it like this:

```
public Handler<T> GetHandler<T>(HandlerType type) where T : BaseClass
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case HandlerType.Diamond: return (Handler<T>)new Handler<DiamondClass>();
        case HandlerType.Silver: return (Handler<T>)new Handler<SilverClass>();
        default: throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
    }
}
```

But now I need to call `GetHandler<DiamondClass>` or `GetHandler<BaseClass>`. And that defeats the purpose of having a method that returns the proper handler based on an enum, without knowing the type. I hoped that I could define a `Type` object and pass it, as such:

```
 Type objType = typeof(DiamondClass);
 var handler = Handler<objType>();
```

But apparently C# won't allow that kind of foolishness. I've gone about this several different ways, and I'd like to think there's a way to do it, but I'm stumped.

---

(I actually did get this working by returning a `dynamic` object, but I'd like to avoid it if at all possible, as it loses any type safety and Intellisense support.)

Comment: What's wrong with `var handler = Handler<DiamondClass>();`, I'm not seeing what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: if you have to check the type inside of a generic method, I'd always question the usefulness of such method.

Comment: @RobA Keep in mind that I simplified the example a lot for the sake of explanation. Part of the problem is that I'd like it to belong on a user control, and I can't define THAT as being generic because it kills the designer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is where *co-variance* comes into play, covariance and contra-variance just work only on interface and delegate, so, to solve your problem, just define a new interface `IHandler` as *co-variant* with [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) which specifies that the type parameter is co-variant:

```
public interface IHandler<out T> where T : BaseClass 
{
}
```

An interface that has a covariant type parameter enables its methods to return more derived types than those specified by the type parameter

It will work. More information is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: Hey, I didn't know we could do that, with the <out T> type! Cool beans. I love learning this stuff. Edit: Just tried it out. You are a lifesaver. It simplified the concept way more than what I thought I had to do. I was WONDERING why it wouldn't accept the child as a type of the base.

Comment: @KChaloux: because this stuff just works with INTERFACE and DELEGATE if I understand you correctly? what does it mean *the child as a type of the base*?

Comment: I'm using objects as type parameters, not primary types. So in the example, `DiamondClass` and `SilverClass` are children of `BaseClass`, and therefore have an "is a" relation to the type of `BaseClass`. A `DiamondClass` is a `BaseClass`... that sounds confusing now that I've typed it out.

Comment: @KChaloux: one more thing this stuff just works in reference type, not value type. Still don't understand your question: "why it wouldn't accept?"

Comment: I was basically just saying that I didn't understand why the compiler wouldn't allow an implicit conversion from Handler<DiamondClass> => Handler<BaseClass>. And now I think I understand. (I wasn't trying to ask another question in the comments, just making a statement).